# Ionic Tab not move to its position after back from single page

Tags: ionic-framework

this is Ionic version 1 question:

i have 4 tabs, each of the tab have it's content, one of them have a list inside it...

so if we have a list inside 3rd tab, then we choose the list and go to single page with back button...

after i tab the back button, it back to 1st tab, not to 3rd tab...

it seems that it cannot remember the position by default, i have tried some workaround like this...

i set the tab just before it enter the previous page:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function (event, data) {
   $ionicTabsDelegate.select($scope.maintabindex);
});
```

with this on-select on each tab:

```
<ion-tab title="Forum" icon-on="ion-tab-fa-headphones" icon-off="ion-tab-fa-headphones" on-select="tabSelected()" href="#/app/home">
```

and then i have this function:

```
$scope.tabSelected = function () {
  $scope.maintabindex = $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex();
};
```

the problem is, the on-select method executed after i back to the parent page (*with tab page), so it cannot working well, because $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex() on-select always give 0 index after i back from the single page to the tabbed page

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ionic go back button should work in those scenarios, be sure that the child's view route is using the same ui-view as the parent tab. If that is the case and it is still not working, it's better for you to override the backbutton on the childs view to go to the parent.

Like this:

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"
    ng-click="myGoBack()">
    <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicHistory) {
  $scope.myGoBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  };
}
```

You can even replace the `myGoBack()` function with `$state.go('parent-tab-view')`